# Associating System.Drawing.Graphics with a device context?

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi

Is there a way of attaching a **System.Drawing.Graphics** class to a device context (HDC) for another window which was retrieved via **GetDC** API function? It is easier than using GDI+ directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20tc8e3b.aspx):

> *Graphics.FromHdc Method*
>
> Creates a new Graphics from the specified handle to a device context.